# ManualResetEvent WaitOne(timeout) returns early. Any ideas why?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm using the ManualResetEvent WaitOne(timeout) method and set the timeout value to 30ms.

I log using log4net at either side of the WaitOne. The log messages show the WaitOne returned false after only waiting for 22ms. What would cause this? A .Net bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem.  It's absurd that a company like Microsoft would release a product with timers that are only 75% accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Win32 documentation on Wait Functions which the .NET methods ultimately use (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687069.aspx):

> Wait Functions and Time-out Intervals
>
> The accuracy of the specified time-out
>   interval depends on the resolution of
>   the system clock. The system clock
>   "ticks" at a constant rate. If the
>   time-out interval is less than the
>   resolution of the system clock, the
>   wait may time out in less than the
>   specified length of time. If the
>   time-out interval is greater than one
>   tick but less than two, the wait can
>   be anywhere between one and two ticks,
>   and so on.

Comment: +1 Was looking for the MSDN article on this, you beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

Either the event is signaled early, or you have timer inaccuracy playing a role in this, since the system clock is, by default, accurate to only 15.625 ms.

Answer (score 0):

In general, don't depend on timeouts to be exact. They'll be approximately correct, not not necessarily perfect. For the same reason, you shouldn't be depending on calls like Thread.Sleep() for timing, the OS doesn't ensure that these calls are timed exactly

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the WaitOne method from .NET calls the Windows WaitOne method. This is not a bug but normal Windows behavior.